# Jquery Ajax: Refreshing multiple divs with different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to refresh the countdown timer of multiple items on my page. Each timer has the class "refresh-item". It works well with just one item, but if I've multiple items (that means different countdown timers also), it seems to only pick the latest id.

This is my JQuery code:

```
function timeLeft()
{   
    var data = $(".refresh-item").attr("data-content"); 
    var dataString = 'case=refresh_item&' + data;

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(result) 
        {   
          $(".refresh-item").html(result);
        }
    });
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    timeLeft();
}, 1000);
```

Each item also has the attribute "data-content" where the specific id of an item is saved. How is it possible to select the specific id of a specific item (to show the individual countdown timer then)?

Comment: you can use $(".refresh-item").each() for archive this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method in jQuery to iterate

```
function timeLeft() {
  $(".refresh-item").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.attr("data-content");
    var dataString = 'case=refresh_item&' + data;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php",
      dataType: "html",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(result) {
        $this.html(result);
      }
    });
  });
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  timeLeft();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use $.each function of jquery:

```
function timeLeft()
{   
    $.each($(".refresh-item"), function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.attr("data-content"); 
        var dataString = 'case=refresh_item&' + data;
         $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "ajax.php",
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(result) 
            {   
              $this.html(result);
            },
          complete: function(){}
    });
    )

}

window.setInterval(function(){
    timeLeft();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: in complete function in ajax request call next request:
 complete: function(){ }